# How to set MANPATH without overriding defaults?

Tags: command-line

I have added extra directories to `$PATH` by exporting `PATH=/my/dirs:$PATH`
But I am not sure if I should do the same to `MANPATH`. Because default `MANPATH` is empty yet `man` command works. I found a command called `manpath` and its manual says `If  $MANPATH  is set, manpath will simply display its contents and issue a warning.`. Does this mean setting MANPATH is not the right way to add directories for `man` command to search for manual pages?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you simply set MANPATH, it overrides the default and you lose access to the standard man pages. For example, `man ls` works before setting MANPATH, but does not work afterwards.

To append a search directory without overriding the default, prefix a colon to MANPATH like this:

```
export MANPATH=":/path/to/custom/man"
```

Adding the colon gives you access to both the standard system man pages and the custom pages referenced in the MANPATH variable.

This answer brought to you by **manpath(1)**:

> If  $MANPATH  is  set,  manpath displays its value rather than
>   determining it on the fly.  If $MANPATH is prefixed by a colon, then
>   the value of the  variable  is  appended  to  the  list determined
>   from the content of the configuration files.  If the colon comes at
>   the end of the value in the variable, then the determined list is
>   appended to the content of  the  variable. If  the  value  of  the 
>   variable  contains  a double colon (::), then the determined list is
>   inserted in the middle of the value, between the two colons.

Answer (score 5):

While the title specifically mentions the `MANPATH` variable, I believe what the original author of the question was partly alluding to was whether **there is a way to "add" a manpage to the system without touching the MANPATH variable in the first place**.

Therefore, in addition to the accepted answer, I would point out that, in a standard configuration, the `manpage` command also seems to look at directories in your `PATH`.

I have not come across the relevant documentation for this, but from personal experimentation, I think the way this works is as follows:

Assume you have a directory in your PATH called `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4`.

Then, `dir4` as *well* as its parent (i.e. `dir3`) will be searched by `manpath`, and *if* one of those directories contains a sub-directory called `man` or `share/man`, then the 'man' directory in question will be added to the output of the `manpath` command.

In practice this means that, e.g., if `/home/user/.local/bin` is in your path, and you also have a directory called `/home/user/.local/share/man`, any manpages contained there will be picked up. Similarly, if something like `/opt/nano/bin` is in your path, then `/opt/nano/share/man` will be picked up.

Note that by "picked up", I mean that the `manpath` command will include that directory in its output! The content of those directories still needs to be compatible with `man` for `man` to pick up valid manpages from within them. In other words, your `home/user/.local/share/man` directory should contain a `man1` directory containing lots of `.1` files, a `man5` directory containing lots of `.5` files, etc, in [groff format](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1158).

**UPDATE: As per the comments below, the `manpath` man pages now fully document this behaviour as of man-db 2.10.0.**

Comment: `man 5 manpath` for the documentation.

Comment: @ReubenThomas thanks Reuben, but that page still doesn't mention the above. The closest thing `man 5 manpath` hints at is that you can have 'fixed' path-to-manpath conversions. I haven't seen any documentation regarding 'relative' conversions as shown above. Not sure why; it's an incredibly useful mechanism!

Comment: Indeed, and I have filed a bug requesting this documentation: https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?61862

Comment: @ReubenThomas excellent! I'll follow it too! :)

Comment: In response to that bug report, there's now a dedicated section for this (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/manpath.5.html#search%20path) and the other manual pages in man-db refer to that.

Answer (score 3):

You should add your custom directories at the end of your `PATH`:

```bsh
PATH=$PATH:/my/dirs
```

This is so your custom directories do not override system binaries and libraries, which could cause a security issue.

You set `MANPATH` the same way (`MANPATH` is empty by default):

```bsh
MANPATH=$MANPATH:/my/dirs
```

You should not need to set a `MANPATH` with well behaved packages, so if it is not broken don't fix it. If it is broken, perhaps you are better filing a bug report ;)

Add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
export PATH=$PATH:/my/dirs
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/my/dirs
```

Comment: Typo in the second statement?  `MANPATH=$MANTPATH:/my/dirs`  Maybe should be: `MANPATH=$MANPATH:/my/dirs`

Comment: What do you mean by "well behaved packages"? I have a whole set of tools that are not installed in the usual places (HPC clusters often put things in /opt). How should they register their man pages without using $MANPATH?

Comment: "well behaved packages" are written to use standard paths and environmental variables. Poorly behaved packages use non standard, at least to Ubuntu, paths such as /opt or do not use environmental variables and thus lead to your observation " I have a whole set of tools that are not installed in the usual places (HPC clusters often put things in /opt)"