# How can I set path so it can be read from GUI and command line by the same program?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc, emacs, .profile

I installed texlive and I want to add it as an environment variable to my Path so that Emacs AucTeX can read it when I start emacs from the GUI or from the command line. So far I've read that emacs only reads files from `~/.profile`.

Therefore my plan is to add texlive to my path in `.profile` to enable emacs GUI to read it and then source `~/profile` from `.bashrc` in order for emacs that is started inside my non-login interactive GNOME terminal to see the path.

Note: I do not have a `.profile` file in my home directory, only in my `/etc` directory, and I'd rather not touch that one, but I have a `.bash_profile` in my home directory. However I read that `.bash_profile` is only run for an interactive login session aka console mode which I don't use.

#### My plan is to create a `.profile` file in my home directory and do the following:

step 1: Create `~/.profile`

Step 2: Add texlive environment variable to path in `.profile`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
```

Step 3: Source `.profile` from `.bashrc`

```
#Adding this at the bottom or start of .bashrc to source .profile when the terminal is opened.

if [-s ~/.profile]; then;
    source ~/.profile;
fi
```

I know that there is a lot of apprehension towards sourcing `.profile` from `.bashrc` due to the risk of causing an infinte loop. However since I am creating a `.profile` file from scratch this will not be a problem as it will not contain any code that references `.bashrc`.

#### My Questions:

1. What do you think of my plan?
2. Do you think it will work?
3. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve it or perhaps other alternatives

*Additional info*: My `.bashrc` only contains code that sources `~/etc/bashrc` and one environment variable that was automatically added by Anaconda: `export PATH="/home/Fedora_User/Anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

Keep in mind that I know gnome-terminal can be run as an interactive login shell but I have never done this and don't know if it will impact the performance of my terminal sessions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, note that if you want `~/.profile` to be read, you'll need to remove `~/.bash_profile`, otherwise `~/.profile` will be ignored by Bash.

You are actually overcomplicating this a bit. PATH is set in `/etc/environment`. It is always `export`ed already, so it does not need to be exported again.

If you make changes to your PATH in `~/.profile` they will be inherited by every shell, whether it is a login shell, interactive or otherwise.

Other variables exported in `~/.profile` will also be passed into the environment, and will be available in every shell. `~/.profile` is read once when you log in to your session, and exported variables stay exported.

Sourcing `~/.profile` in `~/.bashrc` is a bad idea. `~/.profile` sources `~/.bashrc` so you will get an infinite loop. Even if `~/.profile` does not source `~/.bashrc` it is a bad idea to have `~/.bashrc` source `~/.profile` or any other file with assignments like

```
PATH=$PATH:/some/other/place
```

because every time an interactive shell starts another interactive shell the PATH will get extended... you'll end up with your PATH being

```
/original/path:/some/other/place:/some/other/place:/some/other/place
```

etc.

Your MANPATH assignment does not need to include `$MANPATH` but it should start with a leading colon. Please see [this question and its answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197461/how-to-set-manpath-without-overriding-defaults). By default MANPATH is unset and the correct path is dynamically determined (in some way I don't understand), so including the existing MANPATH does nothing. You may need to start the MANPATH assignment with a colon to avoid preventing the path being determined dynamically. As far as I know, the same goes for INFOPATH

Therefore, I suggest:

Rename `~/.bash_profile` `~/.profile`

Add the lines:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux"
export MANPATH=":/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/man"
export INFOPATH=":/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/info"
```

Notes that I have appended to the PATH rather than prepending. You can prepend (put `$PATH` at the end instead of the beginning) if you want to. The first executable found in path lookup is run, so if two programs in different PATH locations have the same name, the one in the directory that comes first (further to the left) in PATH will be run.

Do not add anything to your `~/.bashrc`. Environment variables modified, or new variables exported in `~/.profile` will be available to every shell and don't need to be additionally set elsewhere.

Also note that you should not source `/etc/bash.bashrc` in `~/.bashrc`, because `/etc/bash.bashrc` is already sourced by every interactive shell first*, and we use `~/.bashrc` to make subsequent adjustments.

<sub>*An exception - `/etc/bash/bashrc` checks that the shell is interactive using an unreliable method - it checks that PS1 is set. If you start a shell unsetting PS1, `/etc/bash.bashrc` will not be sourced, even though the shell is interactive. Another exception is when the shell is started with `--norc`, but that's more obvious.</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77439/discussion-on-answer-by-zanna-how-to-set-environment-variables-to-path-so-it-can).

Comment: @Zanna your solution worked out perfectly. Systemd didn't work for PATH, only for MANPATH and INFOPATH. Going back to your answer, I wanted to ask one or two questions: I don't have `/etc/bash.bashrc` instead I have `/etc/bashrc`, my `~/.bashrc` is sourcing `/etc/bashrc` but this system wide file has a conditional statement with PS1 which it uses to check if it is an interactive shell. I checked output of `env` and I don't see `PS1` but if I `echo $PS1` then I get  `[\u@\h \W]\$`. Is it safe to remove the code from `~/.bashrc` that sources `/etc/bashrc`?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia [PS1 isn't an environment variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960551/why-arent-variables-like-ps1-in-printenv). In Ubuntu, `~/.bashrc` should not source `/etc/bash.bashrc` which is read first. I don't know what should happen on your system :/

Comment: @Zanna I have a question about how you quoted the variables `MANPATH` and `INFOPATH`. Is it not better to add the path to these variables by appending the path with a colon to the __path list__ (i.e. `$MANPATH` or `$INFOPATH`) because if you wanted to add a new path to MANPATH like this `MANPATH="usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH"` then if you `echo $MANPATH` you would get `usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/man::usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/man`. May be this can be added as a warning if true.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia as far as I know, the colon has to come first to make sure the dynamic lookup happens. I don't actually know how this works because I have no idea how or where the behaviour is defined, but it's not the same as PATH. AFAIK, the first colon won't be literal and to add on you should do something like `MANPATH=":/some/path:$MANPATH"`

Comment: @Zanna I have a related question about PATH's that I want to ask. I'm not sure whether I can do it here or if I have to open a new question. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Please ask a new question on [unix.se] @MyWrathAcademia :)