# How to add man page for postgres?

Tags: postgresql, paths, manpage

I just install postgres 9.6 inside my `/opt` directory. I want to show the man page of the postgres. While I type `man postgres`, it says,

> No manual entry for postgres.

I think this error may arises due to `$PATH`. I don't know how can I fix the path. Or, should I install postgres inside `usr/local` directory?

Comment: How did you install postgres into /opt? are the man pages actually included? if so, where are they exactly (`/opt/man`? `/opt/share/man`?). In any case, it would be `MANPATH` not `PATH` that would be relevant here.

Comment: I have downloaded the postgres from [postgres installer 9.6.16](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads). I just downloaded it by not changing the default location and values.  Both `/opt/man` and `opt/share/man` pages are not available there.  My man page is available at `usr/share/man` directory. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's better to install postgreSQL through the Ubuntu packages (with apt). Doing that, `man postgres` would work directly. When using custom installers, the fact than manpages are not being readily available is just one of many annoyances you'll see, due to lack of integration with the rest of your system.

But if you have good reasons to do it the hard way, adding non-default directories to the paths searched by `man` is possible and explained at : [How to set MANPATH without overriding defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197461/how-to-set-manpath-without-overriding-defaults#693612)